# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entitySet?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I tried to add data into the database this exception arise. I cant figure out where the problem exist. please help me to find out the where the problem is.

```
[Table("actors_tb")]
public class Actors
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string sex { get; set; }
    public DateTime dob { get; set; }
    public string bio { get; set; }
}
```

This is my DbContext Class

```
public class CinemaDbContext:DbContext
{
    public CinemaDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Actors> actores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Producers> Producer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<movie> movies { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller

```
public ActionResult Actors()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Actors(Actors actors)
    {

    Db.actores.Add(actors);
    Db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: What do the `Producers` and `movie` classes look like?

Comment: @DavidG similar class only.

Comment: Show them or we cannot help.

Comment: How is "Db" injected or instantiated in your controller?

Comment: Is db object not null? if this is true, is your entityset not null?